# Problema al mandar un request a mi servidor Status 403

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-security

Estaba haciendo un POST donde mando dos request serian mi Paciente que seria un Json y un File que seria un JPG. En Postman me anda bien todo correcto pero cuando lo voy a probar en Angular me tira el error de STATUS 403 Forbidden.
Antes cuando no implemente lo de mandar Files , el Post me andaba bien.
Mi pregunta es ¿Necesito configurar algo de en mi apartado de seguridad para poder mandar Files?
Aclaracion : En mi paciente Controller tengo la anotacion Croos Origin

**Codigo de Spring security:**

Security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration{

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    private final LogoutHandler logoutHandler;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(req ->
                        req.requestMatchers("**")
                                .permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/management/**").hasAnyRole(ADMIN.name(), MANAGER.name())
                                .requestMatchers(GET, "/api/v1/management/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_READ.name(), MANAGER_READ.name())
                                .requestMatchers(POST, "/api/v1/management/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_CREATE.name(), MANAGER_CREATE.name())
                                .requestMatchers(PUT, "/api/v1/management/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_UPDATE.name(), MANAGER_UPDATE.name())
                                .requestMatchers(DELETE, "/api/v1/management/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_DELETE.name(), MANAGER_DELETE.name())
                                .anyRequest()
                                .authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .logout(logout ->
                        logout.logoutUrl("/api/v1/auth/logout")
                                .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
                                .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> SecurityContextHolder.clearContext())


                )
        ;

        return http.build();
    }



}
```

Croos Origin Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .allowedOrigins("C:/Users/Lautaro/Desktop/Proyectos/proyecto-clinica-odontologica/frontend/src/imagenes")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }
}
```

Mi service de Post para crear Paciente:

```
crearPaciente(pacienteRequest: Paciente, file: File): Observable<Paciente> {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);
    formData.append('pacienteRequest', JSON.stringify(pacienteRequest));

    return this.http.post<Paciente>(this.apiUrl + 'crearPaciente', formData);
  }
```

Comment: algo me dice que no entiendes bien que es el cors...